# Tag div inside html()

Tags: jquery

If I set content with tag div inside html() and then put to a tag div too, it means I have two tags of div now in id=test? what if set with tag h1 inside html() and then put to a tag h1 too?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function(){
         $("#test").html("<div>Hello world!<div>");
     });
  });
```

here is tag div

```
 <div id="test"></div>

 <button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Cannot understand your question. Can you add more details

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: first I click button with id =btn and then put the html() with "div" tag inside to div tag with id test so it means it have 2 div?

Comment: yes you have 2 divs, what is your expected output?

Comment: what if i put html() with h1 tag inside to a h1 tag too?

Comment: it is treat as one ?

Comment: @medusaeyeofskadi so do you want to add `h1` tags instead of `div` tags tags when using `.html()`? Or do you want to put a `h1` element inside another `h1` element using `.html()` ?

Comment: @NickParsons I have bootstrap alert and it is start with div tag while putting it to div too, it is okay?

Comment: Didn't get your question. Can you please include your expected output??

Comment: @SushilShrestha if I have html("<div>hello world</h1>") so what tag should I use in selector? example: $(" ").html("<div>hello world</div>");

Comment: @medusaeyeofskadi you can't have HTML `<div>hello world</h1>` if its `<div>` use `$("div")` as a selector if it's `<h1>` use `$("h1")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you add inside .html(), will display inside element.

http://jsfiddle.net/brahmpragya/wqret2p4/2/

HTML

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="test1"></div>
<button id="btn">click</button>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn").click(function(){
   $("#test").html("<div>Hello world!</div>");
   //h1 inside the .html
   $("#test1").html("<h1>Hello world!</h1>");
   });
  });
```

Comment: it means i have <h1> <h1>content</h1></<h1>?

Comment: Are you trying to say that if you want to add something inside h1 tag then how can you add?

Comment: $("#test").html("<h1>hello world</h1>") and then put to a tag with h1 with id=test, it is okay?

Comment: You can add html inside <h1> tag also. Please check again this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brahmpragya/wqret2p4/4/

Comment: sorry Im not english speaker fluent, i mean it is okay to have <div><div</div></div>( inside div from html())

Comment: You can add anything inside .html() function. You can do $("#test3").html("<div id='test1'><div id='test2'><div id='test3'>Testing multiple divs</div></div></div>"); I updated the fiddle code with this code. Please check fiddle again.: http://jsfiddle.net/brahmpragya/wqret2p4/11/

Answer (score 1):

**You maybe find it:**

you also set other conditions and you must learn **'text,html,append,prepend'** learn here link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_dom_add.asp

```js
 var counter=0;
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn").click(function(){
     if(counter==0){
      $("#test").append("<div>Hello world!<div>");
     }else if(counter==1) {
      $("#test").append("<h1>Another heading 1<h1>");
     }else if(counter==2) {
      $("#test").append("<h2>Another heading 2<h2>");
     }
     counter+=1;
   });
  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
 <div id="test"></div>
 <button id="btn">click</button>
```